# Add class with opacity not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that loads with the following class.

I am removing and readding that class based off of a checkbox using the following jquery.

The issue is the opacity on the div is correct when the page loads, but when I check then uncheck (remove and add again) the class is added and the pointer events works but not the opacity. Does this have to do with the fact that this div has a form element in it? I have another div with just text elements in it and it works fine.

Here is the html of the non working div.

```js
    $("#add_back").on("click",function(){
     if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
      console.log("checked");
      $(".back_lock").removeClass("disabledElememt");
     }else{
      console.log("unchecked");
      $(".back_lock").addClass("disabledElememt");
     }
    });
```

```css
    .disabledElememt {
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="back-panel-body" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="back-panel-heading" aria-expanded="true">
     <div class="panel-body">
        <label>
          <input id="add_back" type="checkbox">Unlock for <span id="back_price">4.99</span>
         </label>
         <div class="back_lock disabledElememt">
           <div class="form-group">
             <label for="back_txt_0">Text Line 1</label>
       <input type="text" id="back_txt_input_0" class="form-control text_element_input" placeholder="Text Line 1" value="Text Line 1"> 
       </div>                                                                              
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is the HTML element with the id `add_back`?

Comment: Make sure your div has opacity 1 by adding this to your CSS : .back_lock{ opacity: 1; }

Comment: PS from my exp. form-group has float left on bootstrap, so add class row to the parent div.

Comment: not that this has anything to do w/ it, but `opacity` affects all elements that are children, even though it's not really "inherited". a rule of thumb is to always use `rbga(HEX, HEX, HEX, 0.4);` (0.4 being your opacity value)

Comment: if yours is like this it works: http://jsfiddle.net/u1n3o2zb/

Comment: I have added a more complete view of my div structure and the checkbox location. Now I'm thinking maybe because it is in a bootstrap panel, but it appears correct when it loads. and in developer tools it does not look like the opacity is being overridden anywhere it just doesn't render.

Comment: Problem must be somewhere else that you might overwrite something. Code-snippet works just fine

Comment: Well that's disheartening :( I don't know what could override it because it looks fine when I load the page and that is the only listener to that checkbox.

Comment: are you using an ID more then once on the same page?

Comment: I just double checked, but if that was the case I would think the pointer-events: none; wouldn't work. I can see that the class was added properly in the dev tools. It just doesn't render. And actually if I uncheck the opacity in the dev tool panel and then recheck it does show. I'm starting to think it might be a chrome issue.

Comment: I've narrowed it down a bit more. It's definitely some sort of render error. because if I make any change to the page for example $("#SomeUnrelatedDIV").html("Some new text"); the opacity kicks in after that unrelated change